# How do I upgrade to Python3+ in my Docker Compose Container

Tags: python, docker, jenkins, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have a simple docker compose file which is just Jenkins and MongoDB.

```
    version: '3.7'
services:
  jenkins:
    image: jenkins/jenkins:lts
    privileged: true
    user: root
    ports:
      - 8081:8080
      - 50000:50000
    container_name: jenkins
    volumes:
      - ./Docker/FS/jenkins:/var/jenkins_home
      - ./Docker/FS/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      - ./Docker/FS/usr/local/bin/docker:/usr/local/bin/docker
      - ../Data:/var/DataHome
  mongodb:
    image: 'mongo'
    container_name: 'mongodb_container'
    volumes:
      - ./Docker/FS/MongoDB:/data/db 
    ports:
      - '27017-27019:27017-27019'
```

When trying to run a command in jenkins, I noticed that it is running Python 2.7, which isn't ideal.

Is there a simple way to upgrade that to python3+?

Do I have to create a new image to do this? Can you combine multiple images?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new image with a Dockerfile

```
FROM jenkins/jenkins:latest

RUN <cmd to remove python2> && <cmd to install python3>

CMD <cmd to launch your main process>
```

I make the assumption that changing python version does not impact jenkins at all. It might not be the case.